# sourceCpp error: not mach-o or a static library file '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.dylib'

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I've long been a user of RcppArmadillo, but have been unable to compile any programs via sourceCpp since upgrading my OS to Monterey Version 12.3.

Getting the following error:

```
ld: malformed universal file: slice content is not mach-o or a static library file '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.dylib'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_2.so] Error 1
```

It seems like this has something to do with static vs dynamic linking judging by the post [here](https://gist.github.com/loderunner/b6846dd82967ac048439) but I really have no idea.

Comment: See if [this resource helps](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/). It's a problem within your fortran libraries. So this should work.

Comment: This was one of the many solutions that I tried. It didn't help.

Comment: This error happens too when you try to build grub in osdev purposes...

Comment: And changing the `clang` to built-in `gcc` does not fix it. I reported it to GNU team, will see if they fix the issue, or I'm forced to use Linux docker/VM to build my old own osdev project.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same ld error when I upgraded to Xcode 13.3.  I've reverted to 13.2 and my projects build with no errors.  I'll stay with 13.2 until I see more information coming out on what's causing this problem.

Comment: This worked for me. Very disappointing that this is needed. On my other computer, I did actually find a solution without going back to Xcode 13.2. Unfortunately, it's not anything that I can reproduce as I tried a bunch of different stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall RcppArmadillo

-> install.packages("RcppArmadillo", type = "source")

If something wrong, try to modify your makeconf file:

FLIBS =  -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21/11.2.0
#-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm

Comment: Where can one find the makeconf file?

Answer (score 0):

This is from the XCode 13.3 release notes. I guess the issue is related to this change.

> The new chained fixups format is the default linking method when
> targeting macOS 11 or later, iOS 13.4 or later, watchOS 7.0 or later,
> and tvOS 14.0 or later. This new format results in smaller LINKEDIT
> segments in binaries. When targeting earlier operating system
> releases, the linker continues to generate the traditional opcode
> format in LINKEDIT for fixups, rebases, and binds. (85572905)